# are these two laptops (roughly) equivalent?

Tags: laptop, specifications

I was looking at these two Dell laptops  [XPS 15](http://www.dell.com/ie/p/xps-l502x/pd?oc=n00x5m06&model_id=xps-l502x#TechSpec) and [Inspiron Q15R](http://www.pcworld.ie/Product/DELL-Inspiron-Q15R-156andquot-Laptop-Black/305032/301). The XPS is quite a bit more expensive, but as far as I can tell, the most important specifications appear to be almost identical:

- same screen size
- both have 6GB of memory
- same processor speed, 2.00 GHz with Turbo Boost 2.0 up to 2.90 GHz

Although the XPS has a larger hard disk, this doesn't matter to me, because I only care about the specifications that affect performance.

If anything, the XPS should be cheaper because it's being sold directly by Dell, so I suspect I must be missing something, but what is it?

Comment: Voted to close - shopping recommendations off-limits as per the FAQ: http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: Flagged, unfortunately I don't have that much rep yet. Just made my account today.

Answer (score 4):

The Inspiron does not mention having a seperate Graphics Card.
The processor in the XPS is an i7 and the inspiron has an i5.
(Everybody wants the new new new stuff)

The XPS has 64 bit windows 7, and the ad for the inspiron does not mention what it has.

The XPS is designed with higher end stuff in mind(example, gaming). The inspiron could handle it as well but it would not look as pretty.

All in all, Inspiron for everday use (mild graphic intensive tasks), and the XPS for gaming, high end computing.

Answer (score 2):

The XPS is the Dell gaming line, purchased from Alienware a few years back. The Inspiron is the home line. For most purposes, the Inspiron will probably be fine for you, but the XPS is definitely a better computer.

Also from your links, the XPS has a better processor, and is probably running at a higher clock rate internally. It is hard to be more precise since the links are not complete specs.